# Why HttpWebRequest sometime throw OperationCanceledException or WebException.timeout?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

Recently, I came across a strong problem when I use `HttWebRequest` to verify the `timeout` and `ReadWriteTimeout` function in my project.

There are two section code, the first throw

> Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out.
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

```cs
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("https://www.stackoverflow.com");
request.Timeout = 5000;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

HttpWebRequest request2 = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("https://www.stackoverflow.com");
request2.Timeout = 1;
 HttpWebResponse response2 = (HttpWebResponse) request2.GetResponse();
```

And the next section code throw

> Unhandled Exception: System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

```cs
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("https://www.stackoverflow.com");
request.Timeout = 5000;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("https://www.stackoverflow.com");
request.Timeout = 1;
response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
```

I am puzzled why it will throw different exception?

I guess one possible reason is the `keep-alive` is ture by default? but I made my head spin.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm also experiencing the `OperationCanceledException` when calling `GetResponse`. The exception isn't documented on the documentation for `GetResponse`.